# Data is not returning from spring boot using H2 DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have some records in the H2 DB, but data is not returning from the H2 DB using spring boot and there is no error also. the below query is executing in background.

```
 COURSE
=========
 COURSEID
 COURSENAME
 COURSEDESC
 CATEGORY

Hibernate: select course0_.course_id as course_i1_0_, course0_.category as category2_0_, course0_.course_desc as course_d3_0_, course0_.course_name as course_n4_0_ from course course0_
```

Please find below code.

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.model.Course;
import com.example.service.CourseService;

@RestController
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    private CourseService service;

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public List<Course> allCourses(){

        Iterable<Course> i=service.getAllCourses();
        List<Course> c= new ArrayList<Course>();
        Iterator<Course> itr=i.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Course cn=itr.next();
            c.add(cn);
            System.out.println(cn);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

DAO Interface:

```
package com.example.dao;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.model.Course;

public interface CourseDAO  extends CrudRepository<Course, Long>{

}
```

Entity class :

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Course")
public class Course {
    @Id
    private long courseId;
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDesc;
    private String category;

    public long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }
    public void setCourseId(long courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public String getCourseDesc() {
        return courseDesc;
    }
    public void setCourseDesc(String courseDesc) {
        this.courseDesc = courseDesc;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

Service Class:

```
package com.example.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.dao.CourseDAO;
import com.example.model.Course;

@Service
public class CourseService {

    @Autowired  
    private CourseDAO courseDAO;

    public Iterable<Course> getAllCourses(){
        return courseDAO.findAll();
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port = 8090
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin

# To See H2 Console in Browser:
# http://localhost:8080/h2-console
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=false

# ===============================
# DB
# ===============================

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: you can add two breakpoints, first in `CourseService` to check if the records got from DB. second in `CourseController `. I am thinking your problem maybe existed in the second.

Comment: If you don't get the data there is no data. How are you adding the data to the database.

Comment: Already some records are present in the table, I want to retrieve those and show it on browser.

Comment: How did you check that the COURSE table actually contains some data, as you didn't enable h2-console? As you're using an H2 in-memory DB, every time you start your application, a new DB instance is created...

Comment: I ran manually java -jar h2*.jar and added data.

Comment: Given your application configuration: you are running an in-memory H2 stand-alone database: "in-memory" basically means the DB instance is created when your application starts up and connect to its datasource, and it only exists as long as your application is running.  "stand-alone" mode means your H2 DB only support one connection at a time. So, I really doubt you managed to add data in the DB you think you were using. By the way, how did you specify the DB to insert data into when running the h2*.jar (I don't know this way of running H2)?

Comment: Thank you for your information , I am new to h2 db, actually  after running java -jar h2*.jar then I opened h2db console using url